# Issue setting the position of an element

Tags: html, css, position

I am not sure why I am having such an issue with this, but I cannot get a container to show 100% width and have it at the bottom of the parent element.

I am wanting the `home-img-text-container2` and its description to be at the bottom of the image container and for it to be 100% width of the image.

Just like where the arrow is:

[image]

What I have done is changed the position of the containers to absolute:

```
#home-img-text-container1, #home-img-text-container2 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then modified the width and placed it at `bottom:0`

```
#home-img-text-container2 {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In addition the before:

```
#home-img-text-description2:before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The modifications I made are in the max 640px viewport media query.

What am I doing wrong to not get the container2 div to be placed at the bottom of the image and be 100% of the width of the image?

See the fiddle to see what I have done.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgrw2h0c/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you have the home-img-text-container2 element inside of a container, place it out the outside like so

```
...
</div> <!-- End of main container -->

<div class="home-img-text-container2"></div>

</body>
```

Then in your css:

```
.container{
min-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}
```

The 80px is the height of whatever your home-img-text-container2 element is I just used 80px as an example. Make sure you have spaces either side of the "-" as well

```
calc(100vh-80px); will not work
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating your page and everything worked fine. here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<style>

#home-img-text-container1, #home-img-text-container2 {
    position: absolute;
}

#home-img-text-container2 {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

</style>

<div id=home-img-text-description1>
<div id=home-img-text-container2>
Text inside the container2
</div>
</div>
</body>
```